Pass the function argument to run_repeating
Please help me, I can't figure out the library. I want to pass arguments to the ericsson_alarm function. I don't understand how to do this
import logging
import ericsson
import configparser

from telegram import Update
from telegram.ext import ContextTypes, CommandHandler, Application

logging.basicConfig(
    format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
    level=logging.INFO
)


def _ericsson():
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.read('config.ini')
    controllers = {}
    for section in config.sections():
        if 'MSC' in section:
            # Распаковываем словарь в аргументы функции
            controllers[section] = ericsson.EricssonTelnet(**dict(config.items(section)))
            controllers[section].get_alarms()
    return controllers


async def ericsson_alarm(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    controllers = context.job.context['controllers']
    for controller in controllers.values():
        alarm = controller.get_alarms()
        if alarm:
            await context.bot.send_message(chat_id='-ID', text=f"<code>{alarm}</code>")


async def start(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    await context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text="I'm a bot, please talk to me!")


def main() -> None:
    application = Application.builder().token('TOKEN').build()

    controllers = _ericsson()

    # Для отправки сообщений по таймеру
    job_queue = application.job_queue

    # Команды
    start_handler = CommandHandler('start', start)

    # Вызываем функции по-таймеру
    job_queue.run_repeating(ericsson_alarm, interval=10, first=10, data=controllers)

    application.add_handler(start_handler)

    application.run_polling()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

I tried passing arguments through lambda, it still doesn't work, it didn't work through data either

ericsson_alarm() should only take one argument, context. See the documentation

It never uses the update parameter, why do you think it's needed?

you could use run_repeating(lambda context: ericsson_alarm(update, context), interval=10, first=10, data=controllers)

I have nowhere to get update in the main function

Then I don't really understand what the question is about. Why does ericsson_alarm() take it as a parameter if you can't provide it as an argument? As I pointed out above, it never actually uses it, but I guessed that was an unimportant detail you left out of the question.
